# PyQt detect virtual desktop change in x11

Tags: pyqt, pyqt4, virtual, x11, desktop

Is it possible to detect in PyQt if the user has switched from one virtual desktop to another? I can find out the current virtual desktop using wmctrl -d and switch to one using wmctrl -s N .. but if the user decides to switch in another way, can my app detect this?....

Comment: Watch property `_NET_CURRENT_DESKTOP` on root window. I don't think you can do it through Qt, you'll need to use Xlib directly and use [`XSelectInput`](https://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/event-handling/XSelectInput.html) to watch PropertyChange events. I don't know python Xlib bindings, but I'm sure some search engine can help you :)

Comment: Gee thnx, a good pointer. I'll have a look at that. Better than to call wmctrl every 300 ms.

Comment: Following your suggestion I found the module pyewmh
http://ewmh.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ewmh.html#examples  

And now I just run this every 300 ms to keep my workspaceinfo
updated: (import only once)  
    from ewmh import EWMH
    currentdesktop=ewmh.getCurrentDesktop()`

Comment: I don't know those specific bindings, but it would certainly be better if you arranged to get notifications on change of the current desktop property instead of polling it ^^

Comment: True, but yes, I don't know of such an option in PyQt....

Comment: The ewmh thing you're using depends on `python-xlib` package it seems. So perhaps you should use that directly. If it has full Xlib bindings, you'll be able to set up event monitoring properly.

Comment: ah yes that would be better... Thnx for the pointer !